# Using both JFrame and JLabel

Tags: java, jframe, jlabel

I am trying to add both picture and text in JFrame.

When I add both the picture and the text only the picture appears. My guess is that the text is hiding behind it. When I comment out the try / catch block the text appears in the center as it should. Can anybody help me to get the text to appear in front  of the picture?

I removed the path for the pic myself, that is not wrong

```
public class Vindu {

  public Vindu(){
    JFrame F = new JFrame("name");
    JLabel label = new JLabel ("hello world", JLabel.CENTER);
    label.setAlignmentX(0);
    label.setAlignmentY(0);
    F.add(label);

    try{
        F.setContentPane(new JLabel (new ImageIcon  
        (ImageIO.readnewfile))));

        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.print("wrong place");
    }

    F.setResizable(false);
    F.setSize(600, 400);
    F.setVisible(true);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you added a component (`label`) to the frame.  So far so good.

```
F.add(label);
```

In fact, you added it to the frame's content pane because the frame only contains its content pane.  See the [documentation for `JFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html):

> > As a convenience, the add, remove, and setLayout methods of this class are overridden, so that they delegate calls to the corresponding methods of the ContentPane. For example, you can add a child component to a frame as follows:
> >
> > ```
> >   frame.add(child);
> > ```
> >
> > And the child will be added to the contentPane.

Then you replaced the frame's content pane with a new component:

```
F.setContentPane(...);
```

This is why you lost the label.  Instead, add the second label (with the image) to the farme.

```
F.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(...)));
```

You'll also want to learn about [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) at some point to control the layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer to your question by reading the [JFrame documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html).  From that documentation:

> … you can add a child component to a frame as follows:

```
frame.add(child);
```

> And the child will be added to the contentPane.

Thus, your call to `F.add(label)` is identical to `F.getContentPane().add(label)`.  And of course, the very next thing your code does is replace the contentPane entirely.

Since the default contentPane uses a BorderLayout (as described in the JFrame documentation), you could just leave that contentPane in place, and apply BorderLayout constraints to each of your components:

```
F.add(label, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
F.add(new JLabel(ImageIO.read(file)), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Some small side notes:

- In Java, variables should always start with a lowercase letter, by convention.  So your JFrame variable should be `f` or `frame` or `primaryFrame`.  The conventions are fully described [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-135089.html).
- Exceptions are extremely useful for explaining why something has gone wrong.  At the very least, you should use `e.printStackTrace()` in your catch block, so the exception's information is not lost.  (Stack traces are also useful if you encounter a problem and you wish to ask Stack Overflow to help you with it.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get the JLabel over the image:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

try{
    panel.add(new JLabel (new ImageIcon  
            (ImageIO.read(new File("")))));

}catch (IOException e){
    System.out.print("wrong place");
}

JLabel label = new JLabel ("hello world", JLabel.CENTER);
label.setAlignmentX(0);
label.setAlignmentY(0);
panel.add(label);

JFrame F = new JFrame("name");
F.add(panel);

F.setResizable(false);
F.setSize(600, 400);
F.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: This works, as I get both the text and the picture, but the text is to the right and not in the center.

Comment: The above snippet worked fine with Java 6. What is your environment? The exact code snippet you run would help too.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Icon and the text to the same JLabel and display the text centered on the Icon:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel( "Center Text" );
label.setIcon( new ImageIcon( "..." ) );
label.setHorizontalTextPosition( JLabel.CENTER );
label.setVerticalTextPosition( JLabel.CENTER );
frame.add( label );
```